# How can I retreived the recently Viewed documents with Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph

I have to change the discontinued Sharepoint GQL Query to the new Microsoft Graph API. I need to change this query.

```
GraphQuery:ACTOR(ME\, OR(action\:1001\,action\:1003))
```

According to the [replacement suggestion of Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/query-office-graph-using-gql-with-search-rest-api), I must use this query now:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/insights/used
```

> An insight representing documents used by a specific user. The insights returns the most relevant documents that a user viewed or accessed.
>   [See documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/insights_used)

But the new Graph Api don't return the same result than the GraphQuery. The GraphQuery return only the modified document (action:1003) by the user. The "action:1001" is missing in the result.

Actually, the Graph Api return the list of all documents that I have modified or created (and published) in every site collections. But if I'm open a document without any modification, the Graph Api doesn't display. According to the documentation of Microsoft, I supposed to see.

**Context**

1. I'm currently using Sharepoint Online
2. The security is managed by Azure AD.
3. I made the tests with 2 different users. One with all administrative rights and the other is a member user of some sites collection.
4. I'm not using subsite but many site collection.

The Graph Api Delegated permissions are:

1. Read items in all site collections
2. Have full access to all files user can access
3. Real all files that user can access
4. Have full access to user files
5. Read user files
6. Read directory Data
7. Real all Groups
8. Read all users' full profiles
9. Read all user's basic profile
   10.Read and write files that the user selects (preview)
10. Read files that the user selects (preview)

**Questions**

1. Is it because Beta Graph Api is not completely finished?
2. Do I need to make special action to notify Sharepoint that I see the document?
3. Do I need specials permissions?
4. Is it an alternative / another query?

Thanks!

Comment: I also face the same Problem .Anybody has any thoughts here ?

Comment: Any update on this? Anybody got a simple working example?

Comment: Same problem here ! I think it's still in BETA :(